# How can I allow one space, A-Z, a-z, 0-9 in regex?

Tags: java, regex

Mainly I am using regex, and what my code does essentially, is sends a client return code if it does not contain the characters in regex. My problem is, I do not know how to allow spaces.
Currently this is my code, I would like to have allow a space, a-z, A-Z and 0-9.

```
if (username.length() < 1 || username.length() >= 13
    || !username.matches("[a-zA-Z_0-9]"))
{
    session.getLoginPackets().sendClientPacket(3);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Allow a space where? Anywhere in the user name? Only between other characters?

Comment: BTW you can check length with regex too ... [a-zA-Z_0-9 ]{1,13}

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the specific regex class you're using as to what the magic sequences are, but usually either \s, or :space: will work. For some languages where space in the regex isn't ignored you can just put the space in directly: [a-zA-Z_0-9 ] will also work.

Comment: Spaces in regexes are only ignored, if the option `x` is used and its always possible to add a space to a character class, even with `x` enabled. Your regex doesn't check for only one space.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest thing missing is the repetition of the regex.  For example:

```
if (username.length() < 1 || username.length() >= 13 || !username.matches("^[a-zA-Z_0-9 ]+$")) {
    session.getLoginPackets().sendClientPacket(3);
    return;
}
```

The space character must come at the *end* of the character set (which I think is mostly what you were asking).  The other symbols:
* '^' is 'the beginning of the entire string'
* '$' is 'the end of the string' (unless there are newlines...)
* '+' is 'what's in the [...] character set, at least once'

So, add the space at the end of [ ] and use a '+' at the end, and you should have it.

Worth noting you can do everything within the regex, e.g.:

```
if (!username.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]{1,13}$") {
    session.getLoginPackets().sendClientPacket(3);
    return;
}
```

The {1,13} is a boundary saying "at least once, at most 13 times" (inclusive)

I also should point out I believe java supports some shortcuts, e.g. for any upper- or lower-cased letter: [A-z0-9_ ]

--
**EDIT:**

After several comments re: the 'single space', I have to admit I still am not reading the requirement that way.

If the trick is 'only allows one space', this should work:

```
if (username.length() < 1 || username.length() >= 13 || !username.matches("^[A-z0-9_]*\\s[A-z0-9_]*$")) {
    session.getLoginPackets().sendClientPacket(3);
    return;
}
```

Basically, you retain the size boundaries originally, then ensure it is made up of groups of  letters, numbers, and underscore, with exactly one space.

Comment: Two things, the space can be anywhere in the character class and your regex would also match 13 space characters, where the OP wants only one space in the string.

Comment: Doesnt seem to allow a single space :s

Comment: Ugh, caveat in my own edit: \\s isn't really 'space' it's 'any whitespace'.  Adding a literal space character ought to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `[a-zA-Z_0-9]*( )?[a-zA-Z_0-9]*`

This allows exactly one or no spaces within every combination of the characters a-z,A-Z,_,0-9.

Comment: This one allows exactly 0 or 1 space.  It is unclear from the question what exactly he wanted.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
!username.matches("[a-zA-Z_0-9 ]"))
```

OR

```
!username.matches("[a-zA-Z_0-9\s]"))
```

The reason \s is better is because it includes all the white space characters: e.g. tabs

Comment: careful with \s as it matches on all whitespace (spaces, tabs, and line breaks), not just spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
^[a-zA-Z_0-9]+(?: [a-zA-Z_0-9]+)?$
```

the string starts with at least one alphanumeric and then optional a space and one or more alphanumerics till the end if the string.

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?308k6)

Since `[a-zA-Z_0-9]` is equivalent to `\w` you can simplify it to

```
^\w+(?: \w+)?$
```

If you want to be Unicode compliant, you should use the option `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` [see here for more details](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS):

> Enables the Unicode version of Predefined character classes and POSIX character classes.

means, `\w` matches all Unicode code points that have the property Letter and digit.